# How to import packages from inside another package

Tags: python, package

So, I am making an application in python where i am inside a package, and i want to a import a package from outside that older. I have tried os.chdir() but that doesn't work. I have tried to import it by simply saying
[image: A more clear image of what i want to do]

I expect the package to be imported and any file that i want can be used as many times as possible so that i can have a more structed program, and easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

My username is too new to comment so I'll indirectly answer, if your UserData is a module (given there is an `__init__`), and so too is SignLoginLogic, and they are at the same directory level, I have never seen a case where you're importing using your requested method (importing somehow from another module's `__init__.py` directly). See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html. You should be importing SignLoginLogic into your module using something like `from SignLoginLogic import WhatYouWantFromIt` or otherwise a relative import.